# Show the area of the boundary of this set is not 0

Tags: real-analysis

In one real analysis book, it is said that:

> for the points set
>   $S=\{(x,y)|0\le x\le 1, 0\le y\le D(x)\}$, 
> where $D(x)$ is the Dirichlet function, 
> $D(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> 1,  & \text{if $x$ is rational} \\
> 0, & \text{if $x$ is irrational}  \\
> \end{cases}$
>   you cannot find the area of this set since the area of the boundary of this set, $\partial S=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ is not zero.

My question is how to show the area of boundary is not zero.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess, it's meant that the boundary is not [Jordan measure zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure) which is a necessary condition for the Jordan measure of a set to be well-defined. In your case $\partial S = [0,1]^2$ which does not have measure zero since it cannot be covered with open balls of a total area less than e.g. $\frac12$

Answer (score 1):

What is the closure of $S$?

Hint: If $x,y \in [0,1]\times [0,1]$ and $x_n \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$ is such that $x_n \to x$ the you can show that $(x_n,y)\in S$.

What is the interior of $S$? Can you show that if $B$ is some ball inside $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ you can find some $(x,y)\in B$ so that $x \in \mathbb Q$?

These two together tell you what $\partial S$ is...